# Set fixed sizes to custom style button in Firemonkey project

Tags: css, delphi, size, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

For my Firemonkey multi device project in Delphi 10 Seattle i've created a .style sheet with multiple button styles which contain an image. In order to show the image the right way I want to set a fixed size for the button if the styles are set.

Like if you give a button the stylelookup additemstyle it will have width and height of 48 and you can't resize the button. I want to do the same.

How can I accomplish this? I've already tried to lock the style component and set the size there, but I can still resize the button.